# Problem of HTML recovery between brackets with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I come to you today because I encounter a small problem that has been blocking me for quite some time:

to automate a digitized management contract, I use variable home in an HTML string using a WYSIWYG editor whose form is "[[[NAME OF VARIABLE]]]". I then retrieve these variables and I have them transformed into text fields so that the user can fill them via a form.

I am currently using Angular 5.

My concern is that one of these variable has messed with the editor and gives it during the recovery in JS:

```
'[[[blablabla</span><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">]]]',
```

So, when assigning values submitted by the user, it is not taken into account .. What I intended to do was make a regex to replace the html code by a vacuum but it is the I block, I'm doing tested and I got to this stage:

```
/\[\[\[(<[^>]+>)\]\]\]/gi
```

but I confess that the regex and me, it's 10: D

Can anyone unlock me? If need more detail, there are no worries!

Thank you in advance !

(sorry for my english, i'm french)

Comment: Looks like you want `s.replace(/\[\[\[[\s\S]*?]]]/g, function (m) { return m.replace(/<[^<>]+>/g, ''); })`

Comment: Waw, I love you !!
Thank you for your very fast response !! It's right what I need!
it's been 3 days that I'm on it haha

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match all substrings between `[[[` and `]]]` and then only replace substrings matching the `<[^<>]+>` pattern inside those matches:

```
s = s.replace(/\[\[\[[\s\S]*?]]]/g, function (m) { 
    return m.replace(/<[^<>]+>/g, ''); 
})
```

The first pattern matches

- `\[\[\[` - a `[[[` substring
- `[\s\S]*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `]]]` - a `]]]` substring.

The `g` modifier finds multiple occurrences of the pattern inside the input string. The match is passed to the callback method (`m` is the matched text) and the `.replace(/<[^<>]+>/g, '')` is only applied to the `m` text that is returned after `<`, 1+ chars other than `<` and `>` and then `>` matches are replaced with an empty string.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! it helps me a lot and I understand better the result!